# LeetCode "Paint House" problem: time limit exceeded despite O(N) solution?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the [Paint House](https://leetcode.com/problems/paint-house/description/) problem on LeetCode. Here is my attempted solution:

```
import math


class Solution(object):
    def minCost(self, costs):
        """
        :type costs: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: int
        """
        if not costs:
            return 0
        if len(costs) == 1:
            return min(costs[0])
        return min(costs[0][color] + self.minCost(
            [exclude(costs[1], color), *costs[2:]])
            for color in range(3))


def exclude(arr, color):
    new_arr = arr.copy()
    new_arr[color] = math.inf
    return new_arr
```

Basically, at each house, it considers the cost of choosing each color for that house and excluding that choice for the next house (by setting the cost to infinity). I believe this should be linear time because the recursive calls are made until the end of the `costs` array is reached.

Am I mistaken? Does the solution have the right time complexity, but just runs a little slower than the time limit imposed by LeetCode?

Comment: What is the paint house problem?  You provided a link that requires a login to another site.  That doesn't qualify as a description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that each call to `minCost` which does not satisfy the base cases generates *three* recursive calls so that the number of calls increases exponentially. So this is not a linear-time solution and it is right that the time limit is exceeded.